# Run 2 docker mysql containers simultaneously with docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker

I need help setting up 2 mysql docker containers at the same time.

Right now I spin up my mysql docker container via docker-compose like this:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_database
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ********
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ********
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
    ports:
      # <Port exposed> : < MySQL Port running inside container>
      - '3308:3306'
```

What I've tried is copy-pasting the docker-composse.yml into a different folder and changing it a little

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_other_database
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ********
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ********
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
    ports:
      # <Port exposed> : < MySQL Port running inside container>
      - '3310:3307'
```

I run `docker-compose up` for both of them and both start up normally. I can connect to port 3308 just fine but I cannot connect to port 3310. I get

```
Can not read response from server. 
Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
```

How do I set up my docker-compose.yml files so I get 2 mysql containers that run simultaneously?

Comment: On a side note, instead of copy pasting and having different dockerfile(or compose) you could use the `--scale` command. Reference [scale](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_scale/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the wrong Port on the second config. Mysql runs on port **3306**

Change `3310:3307` to `3310:3306`.

The whole config:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_other_database
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ********
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ********
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
    ports:
      # <Port exposed> : < MySQL Port running inside container>
      - '3310:3306'
```